# Is it possible to pass keyword argument from command line?

Tags: php, command-line

I want to pass keyword argument to a php script via command line.
Something like this:

```
php some_script.php --arg1 val1 --arg2 val2
```

How should I do to accomplish this? Is it possible? Or there is a common practice to do it? Thank you very much.

Comment: Use [`getopt`](http://php.net/getopt).

Answer (score 1):

In PHP there is an array of parameters pre-defined:

`php script.php val1 val2`

You can access your arguments over

```
$argv
```

http://php.net/manual/de/reserved.variables.argv.php

```
<?php
    // $argv[0] is 'path_to_script.php'
    $arg1= $argv[1];
    $arg2= $argv[2];
?>
```